# javascript pop-up window

Tags: javascript, html

In some web pages, when we stop mouse cursor on some words (e.g. some popular movie star names) on the web page, a pop-up box near the words will show-up, showing maybe some related pictures for the move star, a short summary for the movie star, and related twitter link for this movie star. Then we can move mouse on the pop-up windows to click for picture or twitter link.

When the mouse cursor is leaving such pop-up window, the pop-up window will disappear automatically.

Are there any existing ready to use code to implement such effect?

BTW: I remembered some web site has some underline keyword, and when mouse move over such keywords, a related Ads windows will pop-up around the keyword. This is the effect I am looking for in this question.

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: What are you asking? I don't see any question marks.

Comment: what's the question exactly? How to implement this? There are many ways...

Comment: Sorry Josh, my mistake. Here is what I am asking "Are there any existing ready to use code to implement such effect?".

Comment: Hi Alex, sorry it is my mistake. Here is what I am asking "Are there any existing ready to use code to implement such effect?", I am not a javascript guru and please let me know a simple and easy way to implement. What I want to have is pop-up window around the keyword, not at the corner of the whole web page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [jQuery TOOLS][1] - the tooltips.

[1]: http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html jQuery Tools

Comment: Which component or more detailed link for jQuery tools shall I use to implement the effect I am looking for?

Comment: Hi Alex, which component from jQuery tools should I use to implement such effect?

Comment: George - look at the tooltip tool: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the HoverCard effect?

http://www.shoutmeloud.com/gravatar-hovercards-for-wordpress-org-blogs.html

http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_ui_hovercard.js.source.html

Comment: Yes, this is what I am looking for. Any existing ready to use code?

Comment: The above links are dead as of 2017.

Google's Closure Library for Hovercards seems to be still available from here: https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.ui.HoverCard.html

Answer (score 1):

I think `onmouseover` is what you need to look into

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to use the `title` attribute in some HTML elements.

An example from this page:

```
<span class="reputation-score" title="your reputation score; view reputation privileges">611</span>
```

When you hover over your reputation you get the message in the title attribute.  It's not as fancy as some of the other answers but it is quick and simple.

Comment: @George.  I added an example.